# Flexible image scaling / stretching like in music notation

Tags: css, svg, layout, notation

I have a difficult layout problem I can't find a solution for. Although the subject seems to be music notation, in my case it is actually a layout/css issue.

There are several rows of bars (divided by the vertical lines, see graphic #1 below). Each bar is a separate svg file. They all have the same height and add up to a length of 100%.

[image]

This is easy for bars of the same length, but gets very tricky for different sizes.

Graphic #2 has been composed in a music notation software. The last bar is bigger than 25% and the first three bars get squished together. Yet, all bars keep their height and individual notes preserve their form.

[image]

Furthermore, there are edge cases where super long bars push the following bars to the next row (see graphic #3).

[image]

So why not layout full rows in a music notation software?

Because each bar is a separate post with meta information and I want to string these posts together instead of creating new posts with full length lines done in a music notation software and meta information for each individual bar attached to it.

Can this be achieved without music notation software but with individual (svg-)images, css, and maybe jquery?

- line length should always be 100%.
- all svgs have the same height, but a different length depending on the notes within each bar.
- depending on their content, bars should adjust their width and - in edge cases - break to the next line (see graphic 3.)

I already tried:

- a row of floating 4 divs with 25% width. 
  Good solution for bars with the same length. But images with different width/aspect ratio get squeezed and look awfully distorted.
- a row of divs displayed as table cells
  so each div has a flexible width. But depending on the image/bar sizes, the table row gets longer than 100%.

**EDIT:**
As suggested by @yinken I implemented a flexbox solution. It works great in terms of general layout/container flow. But the problem of scaled images resulting in an uneven look remains.

I added `.bars img { min-width: 100%; }` to avoid gaps between images.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good usage case for Flexbox. In the code below, each bar of music is set to take up a minimum of 25% of each row's width, so you will have a maximum of 4 bars per row at any given time. Every subsequent bar will automatically wrap to a new row,

If the content of a bar becomes larger than that, it will grow larger accordingly. If you only have one bar in a row, it's size will automatically fill 100% of its width.

```css
  .sheet-music {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .bar {
    height:80px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-basis: 25%;
    margin-bottom:20px;
  }
  .bar:nth-of-type(even) {
    background: #ccc;
  }
  .bar:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background: #eee;
  }
```

```html
<div class="sheet-music">
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your flexbox example! Regarding the flow of containers, this is a very elegant solution. My problem arises when I insert bar graphics of different sizes in each container. I edited my original post to include another image. The graphics scale up and down where they should keeps the same height but not get squashed.

Comment: I need to write drum scores. Seems like vexflow supports percussion notes, but there's no documentation.